# wxWidgets and wxLocale -- gettext and the symbolic language inside the application?

Tags: internationalization, wxwidgets

I am rewriting our older application using wxWidgets. The application uses the old, *home made* mechanism of language dictionaries, and I would like to replace it using the standard `gettext` way supported by the wxWidgets.

The problem is that the application does not use user-readable strings inside, but rather symbolic identifiers that should be translated using the chosen language dictionary. In other words, the translation should always happen. For example, the code says:

```
wxMenu * mnuParamSelect = new wxMenu();
mnuParamSelect->Append(wxID_mnuiParamSelect,
                       _("mnuiParamSelect"),
                       _("hlpParamSelect"));
```

This way, it uses a *default symbolic language* that must be *always* translated (like the symbolic `mnuiParamSelect` into `Select the parametres...` for English, `Vyber parametry...` for `cs_CZ`, etc).

It seems that this is not usual approach considering `gettext`. I am very new to `gettext`. Should I be aware of any problem related to the *symbolic language identifications* approach?

Thanks for your time and experience,

Petr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, the first big problem is that creating new translations will be difficult (or at least time consuming), as the translator will only see the symbolic id, and needs to find the corresponding English message in a different file.

Second problem: If you are using printf-style formatting like "%d files", gettext (i.e. msgfmt) won't do any syntax checking for you if the symbolic ids do not contain those format specifiers. So if your translator adds one "%d" too many for example, the application will probably crash when used with that translation.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. On the other hand, the applicaton is not small any more. It already uses the symbolic identifications internally. We use four language versions. This way, we have some scripts and a text-file based database, and tools for synchronizing the translations (i.e. what is not translated yet in what language). After gaining some experience with po files, I can probably generate them easily. Anyway, does gettext check the number of printf placeholders if the text is not symbolic?

Comment: Yes; not only does `msgfmt -c` check the number of printf placeholders, it also checks that they are in the correct order. Actually, I don't see the point of moving to gettext if you intend to use it in such an unorthodox way and avoid taking advantage of features it offers.

Comment: Actually, I may be mixing the old app approach, and the classical gettext in new parts of the application. The main reason for studying the possibility is migration to wxWidgets GUI where the work with `_("automatically translated texts")` seems to be natural. On the other hand, I need to replace a lot of GUI related code, and if something can be automated or be done *mechanically* by hand (without too much rethinking)...

Comment: I don't think it would be terribly hard to write a script that replaces symbolic ids in your source code with the corresponding strings from e.g. the English .po file. That is, if the gettext way is the way you want to convert to.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to formulate the related question soon.

Answer (score 0):

po files can include a `msgctx` (message context) field, which forms part of the id.

So you can use `msgctx` for you symbolic name, `msgid` for your default locale text, and `msgstr` for the translated text.